# PDFBox : small pdf file can't be open in PDFormXObject

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a small pdf file that Pdfbox can't open.
After analyze, PDFCloneUtility.cloneMerge() is extremly consumer in memory and calculation,and never finished or exit with JavaHeapSpace although 32Gb ram, but transformation in picture is noit a problem and really fast.

What is special or bad with my PDF ?
[PDF File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/583ee85f7d433f2b523fe27dea6df48520210701163459/b21644)

```java
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(imported);
new LayerUtility(pdDocument).importPageAsForm(pdDocument, 0);
```

Comment: Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5232

Comment: I wonder if this is somehow a recursion because it comes from the same document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed `importPageAsForm` appears not to be fully tested for identical source and target documents.

In the case at hand the PDF has OCGs (optional content groups, in some GUIs also called layers), so the `LayerUtility` attempts to import OCGs from source to target, i.e. into itself.

Unfortunately this is something the `PDFCloneUtility` used underneath does not expect and in `cloneMerge` runs into a never ending loop in

```
                  COSArray array = (COSArray) base;
                  for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
                  {
                      ((COSArray) target).add(cloneForNewDocument(array.get(i)));
                  }
```

where `base`, `array`, and `target` point to the same `COSArray`.

If one extends the check at the top of `cloneMerge`

```
          if( base == null )
          {
              return;
          }
```

to

```
          if( base == null || base == target )
          {
              return;
          }
```

the endless loop is prevented.

One has to check, though, whether this has unwanted side effects.

Comment: Thanks @mkl . Snapshot available at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.25-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thank you for your promptness. My problem is solved.